# making Circle In uiView using view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

How can i make a circle when I tap on screeen (randomly not the clicked position) ! 
PS : Tap gesture should be in ViewController File Not "my own custom view file"

Comment: You will need to explain exactly what you want to achieve? Adding to that, you should also let us know what you've tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

First define tap gesture in your view controller.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *letterTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapgesture:)];

[self.view addsubview:letterTapRecognizer];
```

On this tap gesture method call a `circleview`.

```
- (void)tapgesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender 

{
circleview *temp = [[circleview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:temp];

}
```

Implement - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method in   circleview.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, 10.0, 10.0));

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
}
```

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *letterTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapgesture:)];

[self.view addsubview:letterTapRecognizer];

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *letterTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapgesture:)];

[self.view addsubview:letterTapRecognizer];

define this ViewController's viewdidload method ?

Comment: Please can u send the file on :
email : d_y1234@hotmail.com

Comment: i still having problem bro :/

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, drawing doesn't happen in the `UIViewController` but rather, in the `UIView`

If you're insistent on doing the drawing in the view controller, the only way to do that would be to create a `CALayer`, set it's delegate to the view controller, and do your rendering in `drawLayer:inContext`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CALayer* layer;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    layer = [CALayer new];
    layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    layer.delegate = self;
    [layer setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view.layer addSubLayer:layer];
}

-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    ... do your drawing here...
}
```

Again, the more conventional approach would be to subclass UIView and handle all the drawing there.